# How is comparing operator '==' for NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, operators, nsobject

How is comparing operator '`==`' for `NSObject`?
Method `-isEqual:` works fine for me, but when I'm using `-isEqual` I need to check if objects exists. With '`==`' I don't need to check this but where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: Do you need to compare `NSObject` or check its existence?

Comment: What do you mean by "but with it I need to check if objects exists"?

Comment: `==`, when used with pointers, checks whether the *pointers* are equal.  You could have two NSStrings that both said "ABC", but would compare not-equal because they were *different* objects with *different* addresses.

Comment: @Monolo I mean when I'm comparing with -isEqual method, I need to check if objects are null

Comment: (And, frankly, if you don't understand this sort of thing you're going to be lost programming in Objective-C.)

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks for advice. Please compile this: NSString *anA = @"a";
  NSString *anotherA = @"a";
  if (anA == anotherA) {
    NSLog(@"Hello Hot Licks");
  }

Comment: Those will compare equal with `==` because they're both pointers to the exact same object.  If you had, on the other hand, gotten one of your strings by substringing another string, they would not compare equal with `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver and a
>   given object are equal. (required) This method defines what it means
>   for instances to be equal. For example, a container object might
>   define two containers as equal if their corresponding objects all
>   respond YES to an isEqual: request. See the NSData, NSDictionary,
>   NSArray, and NSString class specifications for examples of the use of
>   this method. If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash
>   value. This last point is particularly important if you define
>   isEqual: in a subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass
>   into a collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

if you do like this

```
if([obj1 isEqual:obj2])
```

and `obj1`, or `obj2` is `nil` then you will get `NO`. (if this is what you meant by your question) 
- Now

```
if(obj1 == obj2)
```

This is a pointer comparison. [Pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Comment: thanks, I didn't understand this, why when I'm comparing 2 NSString-s or NSArray-s return YES. This explain why.

Answer (score 1):

The == operator tests whether the two expressions are the same pointer to the same object. Cocoa calls this relation “identical”

To test whether two objects are equal, you would send one of them an isEqual:

Comment: This I know, but why 2 different NSString objects can be equal with == operator? This was question.

Comment: Just because of : NSString *stringA=@"abc"; NSString *stringB=stringA; if (stringA==stringB) {NSLog(@"==");}

Comment: While I'm sure @ArmandDOHM's answer is what the question wanted to know, it might be worth noting that in the example given stringA and stringB both point to the self same NSString object. Two different NSString objects CANNOT be equal with '==' operator.

Comment: I think you didn't take my answer seriously @igor Bidiniuc

Comment: @Maximus, I checked it now, yes you're right